# I want to get value fron Integer key, javascript

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, object

I want to get value fron Integer key
example :

```
id:55,
'15':12.05,
'16':13.95,
'17':14.44
```

if i want value from 17 
How should i query in nodejs

Comment: `const value = object['17'];`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). It's not at all clear what that code block is meant to show. Please show us valid syntax for whatever structure you're trying to get information from, and explain what research you've done and what attempts to get the information you've tried.

Comment: it show undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Using the operator [] can solve your problem.

```
data["17"] or data[17]
```

Your data doesn't include key '17' so it will return **undefined**

```json
{ '50': 8.8, '51': 10.1, '52': 11.5, '53': 12.8, '54': 14.2, '55': 15.6, '56': 17.1, '57': 18.5, '58': 20, '59': 21.5, '60': 23.1, '61': 24.6, '62': 26.2, '63': 27.8, '64': 29.4, '65': 31, '66': 32.4, '67': 33.8, '68': 35.1, '69': 36.4, '70': 37.7, '71': 39, '72': 40.2, '73': 41.5, '74': 42.7, '75': 43.9, '76': 45 }
```

Please check your data again.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is here or not. My steps are Extract data from Mongo And I will get information in the format that I have given. And then I want to check the value from the key, with my key in numbers. I have tried, tried to follow the instructions. But it still grows underfinded

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[]` operator to get the value - `myObj['17']`, or even `myObj[17]`.

Comment: my data is 

{
  '50': 8.8,
  '51': 10.1,
  '52': 11.5,
  '53': 12.8,
  '54': 14.2,
  '55': 15.6,
  '56': 17.1,
  '57': 18.5,
  '58': 20,
  '59': 21.5,
  '60': 23.1,
  '61': 24.6,
  '62': 26.2,
  '63': 27.8,
  '64': 29.4,
  '65': 31,
  '66': 32.4,
  '67': 33.8,
  '68': 35.1,
  '69': 36.4,
  '70': 37.7,
  '71': 39,
  '72': 40.2,
  '73': 41.5,
  '74': 42.7,
  '75': 43.9,
  '76': 45
}


and i try to your advice but it show undefined.'

Comment: @NONTAKORNHANSUKYONG you don't have key for "17", what do expect it to retrun?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer already. Because I forget to attributed variable in mongoose model. Thank you for help.